# Ionic/Angular components aren't showing up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components

I am new to ionic but pretty well versed in angular.
I am trying to add a component to my ionic/angular project but I can't seem to get new components to show up correctly. I think it's a routing issue.
I have generated new components both with `ionic g component my-component` and `ng g c my-other-component` and they seemingly generate as normal. But then, when I try to add the new component to a page via `<app-my-component></app-my-component>` it doesn't show up.
I noticed that when my new components are generated, they are generated with their html, ts, spec.ts, and scss files but not with a module file.
Is that the problem?
If so, how do I get ionic to automatically add the module file/routing to newly created components?

Comment: Angular components do not need a module file to be shown correctly. There is a difference between a component and a module. Thats also not the problem why ionic isn't showing it. Please add a [MRE] of your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use to include custom components in an Ionic project is as follows.

Firstly, generate any components to be within a 'components' directory to keep things organized. Using your example, that would be with the command `ionic g component components/my-component`.

Then create a common components module 'components.module.ts' at the root of the components directory. Use the following format for its contents:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

// In this example, MyComponent would be imported as follows:
// import { MyComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [/*Declare your components here. e.g. MyComponent*/],
  providers: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    // Add modules to import here. e.g. FormsModule
  ],
    exports: [/*Same as declarations*/]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

And finally, add the ComponentsModule to the list of imports in 'app.module.ts' and import it.

All components added to ComponentsModule should now be included in your project upon recompilation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things in ionic: Components and Pages. Even though they are not very different but Pages are components with module as well as routing-module.
you can generate a page using:

```
ionic generate page page-name
```

For more information, you can visit [pages and components](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/testing#pages-and-components)